# Java Simon Says Scanner Issue

Tags: java

So we're trying to create a Simon Says game in java and it works pretty well except for the fact that everytime after the games asks for "what simon says" it includes an extra box for scanning user input. I don't know how to get rid of it without messing up that entire part of code. It all compiles but playing the actual game leads to almost an automatic loss. Here is the code:

```java
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;

public class simonSays
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("this is simon says. repeat what simon says.");
        String simon = "";
        String newString = ""; 
        boolean cont = true;

        System.out.println("are you readY? enter yes or no.");
        String read = keyboard.nextLine();
        String ready = read.toLowerCase();

        while (cont && ready.charAt(0) == 'y')
        {
            System.out.println("simon says:");
            simon += rand();
            sp(simon);

            System.out.println("what did simon say?");
            for(int i = 0; i <= simon.length(); i++)
            {
                newString += keyboard.nextInt();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < simon.length(); i++)
            {
                if (newString.charAt(i) == simon.charAt(i))
                {
                    cont = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("you lose.");
                    cont = false;
                } 
            }
        }
        while (cont && ready.charAt(0) == 'n')
        {
            System.out.println("ok bye");
            break;
        }
    }
 
    public static String rand()
    {
        int ran =  (int)(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
        String random = String.valueOf(ran);
        return random;
    }
 
    public static void sp(String a)
    {   
        for(int j = 0; j < a.length(); j++)
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println(a.charAt(j));
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            System.out.println("\n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that 
"i <= simon.length()"
should be
"i < simon.length()"

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few logic errors in your code. First of all

```java
for(int i = 0; i <= simon.length(); i++)
{
    newString += keyboard.nextInt();
}
```

Method [nextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) does not read a single digit, it reads an entire number. In any case you are comparing the number generated by your code with the number that the user inputs and you are comparing them as strings, so you can replace method `nextInt` with method [nextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--). And since you are comparing strings, you can use method [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-).

Also

```java
Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
```

I think you want method [interrupted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted--) since

> The interrupted status of the thread is cleared by this method

Note that you do not need to explicitly import classes that are in package `java.lang`, so you can remove the following imports.

```java
import java.lang.*;
import java.lang.Math;
```

By the way, the first import, above, already includes the second one.

Also I think that your game is too easy since in every round you simply add another digit to the existing number. So I changed the code such that in each round the number of digits is increased by one but all the digits are generated randomly.

Nonetheless, I recommend that you learn how to debug your code. All programmers need to know how to debug code. If you are using an IDE, like [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), then it should have a debugger. You should learn how to use it.

Here is my rewritten version of your *Simon Says* game.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SimonSay {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("This is Simon says. Repeat what Simon says.");
        String simon = "";
        String newString = "";
        boolean cont = true;

        System.out.println("Are you ready? Enter yes or no.");
        String read = keyboard.nextLine();
        String ready = read.toLowerCase();

        while (cont && ready.charAt(0) == 'y') {
            System.out.println("Simon says:");
            simon = rand(simon.length() + 1);
            sp(simon);

            System.out.println("What did Simon say?");
            newString = keyboard.nextLine();
            if (!simon.equals(newString)) {
                System.out.println("You lose.");
                cont = false;
            }
        }
        if (ready.charAt(0) == 'n') {
            System.out.println("OK. Bye.");
        }
    }

    public static String rand(int len) {
        StringBuilder random = new StringBuilder(len);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            int ran = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
            random.append(ran);
        }
        return random.toString();
    }

    public static void sp(String a) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length(); j++) {
            try {
                System.out.println(a.charAt(j));
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.interrupted();
            }
            System.out.println("\n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n ");
        }
    }
}
```